# Is there a list of countries that require six months' validity remaining on your New Zealand passport?

Tags: passports, new-zealand-citizens

As we know, [some countries require you to have six months remaining on your passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/23041/101) in order to visit.

I'm uncertain as to whether this differs for each origin country - for example, one list seems to suggest some countries have different rules for the US as a result of bilateral agreements.

I'm going to be travelling later this year and could enter the sketchy period where there'll be 5-7 months left on my passport towards the end of the trip. It's a New Zealand passport, so I'm trying to find a list of the countries that I'll need a new passport for - if I don't need to get one yet, I'd rather not.

Comment: I looked into this recently. USA (ESTA) ICE officer told me 3 months from date of arrival as the esta is valid for 90 days. Canadian embassy website said 6 months from date of arrival. Egypt requires a full 6 months on exit according to a conversation I had with the London consulate. the NZ department of foreign affairs website said there is no comprehensive list and to check with each embassy before travelling. Don't have time to turn this into a proper answer - maybe tomorrow night.

Comment: the last point on the list suggest the NZ government is considering moving to the UK system of offering a credit on early renewal which would be swell. http://www.passports.govt.nz/Five-year-passports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear there is no official list rather an [official suggestion](http://www.passports.govt.nz/Before-you-travel---check-your-passport#expiry) to check with the country you are traveling to.

I suggest you ask separate questions for the countries you intend on visiting.

Comment: @Geeo Splitting doesn't really work when there are a couple of hundred I hope to travel to ;)

Comment: Actually, splitting this question into individual countries of an itinerary might be closed as trivial, because looking them up is possibly a simple wiki search, which this site is trying not to emulate. :) "Is there an existing list" was a perfectly valid question. "What are the countries that ... x" would not have been. :)

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica A couple of hunded? Carry your bags?? :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon 80 down so far ;)

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica 35 here. May not be many more, alas. TBD.