# Entering Germany with a Passport that is about to expire in 6 mouths

Tags: passports, germany

My (Israeli) passport expires on 15/3/2018, and I need to fly from Israel to Germany on 10/9/2017 for 4 nights. I won't be able to renew my passport before the flight in the normal process, only in an express process which costs considerably more and is a greater hassle.

I have asked the Israeli ministry of interior and they told me that I'll be able to leave the country (and come back) as long as my passport is valid, even on the last day before it expires, but from my knowledge, international travel requires a passport that is valid for 6 months.

Will I be able to enter and leave Germany with a passport that expires in 6 months and a few days?

Comment: International travel does not require a passport that is valid for 6 months (although it's common), it's up to every country to set such limits.

Answer (score 0):

As RedBaron says, it's a duplicate of [Does Germany enforce a six month passport rule](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61035/does-germany-enforce-a-six-month-passport-rule). Well, almost - that one was for a USA passport.

Anyway, the answer is the same - it's 3 months, not 6.

A [Timatic search using the Emirates site](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IL&NV=Israel&DC=DE&DV=Germany&h=8aa384dd6499b7c3b8c5eb5bc31e6fdfeaafde23) says:

> Document Validity:
>   Passports and other documents accepted for entry
>   must be valid for a minimum of 3 months beyond the period of intended
>   stay.

Comment: As noted in the answers to the linked question for visa exempt nationals (USA, Israel), the border guards can interpret duration of stay as 90 days. So, in theory your passport needs to be valid for your duration of stay (three months) and additional three months at the time of arrival which does give a total of six months.