# Revocation of US Passport when traveling abroad

Tags: passports

How does one know if one's US Passport has been revoked while traveling abroad?

Comment: You're in the SVO transit area and see your face on the news.

Comment: Related: [If, like Edward Snowden, your passport was revoked or cancelled, how could you travel?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/18394/3221)

Answer (score 4):

[22 CFR § 51.65](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/51.65) Notification of denial or revocation of passport.
(a) The Department will notify in writing any person whose application for issuance of a passport has been denied, or whose passport has been revoked. The notification will set forth the specific reasons for the denial or revocation, and, if applicable, the procedures for review available under 22 CFR 51.70 through 51.74.

I imagine in practice the first time a traveler would become aware of the revocation, if abroad, and if nobody at home opened the mail, would be when they were (at best) denied entry or exit by authorities that share information with the US.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't see any straightforward mechanism for enquiry, though a US embassy should be able to advise a citizen if their passport had been revoked. [Here](http://en.chessbase.com/portals/4/files/images2/2004/fischer08.gif) is a sample of a revocation letter, in this case sent by the local embassy.

Comment: You seem to be confusing Julian Assange and Edward Snowden. Assange is in the Ecuadorian embassy in London but is  an Australian citizen who has never had a U.S. passport and hasn't, to the best of my knowledge, had his Australian passport revoked. Snowden had his U.S. passport revoked but is living in Russia.

Comment: @David Hopefully conflating the two gentlemen does not detract from the usefulness of the answer.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Agreed, though it does make the first paragraph something of a distraction.

Comment: That's what edits are for